# Trouble switching jcarousel from vertical to horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, jcarousel

I am using jCarousel and I want to switch a carousel configured to vertical to horizontal at a certain screen width.  My main code on page load is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var lCarousel = $('.jcarouselLarge').jcarousel({
        // Configuration goes here
        wrap: 'circular',
        animation: 'slow'
    })
    var sCarousel = $('.jcarouselSmall').jcarousel({
        // Configuration goes here
        wrap: 'circular',
        vertical: true,
        animation: 'slow'
    })

    $('.jcarouselSmall').jcarouselAutoscroll({
        interval: 6000,
        target: '+=1',
        autostart: true,
        carousel: sCarousel
    })

    $('.jcarouselLarge').jcarouselAutoscroll({
      interval: 6000,
       target: '+=1',
       autostart: true,
      carousel: lCarousel
    })
    ;
```

Then I'm trying to invoke

```
    if ($(window).width() <= 990) {

        $('.jcarouselSmall').jcarousel({
            vertical: false
        });

        }
```

I've tried various methods but none seem to work for me.  Do I need to set vertical after a reload?  The above code seems to stop the carousel working all together.  I know that the carousel can detect an implement vertical scroll based on dimensions, is this interfering with my setting?

Thanks,

Amanda

Answer (score -1):

Think you may need to destroy the carousel first and then do the switch to vertical

Edit to add you need to increase the container width of the carousel and it should switch from vertical to horizontal

Comment: It auto detects the direction apparently I was told:   "It is important, that you set the width to 20000em and height to auto for a horizontal carousel, and width to auto and height to 20000em for a vertical carousel. If you do that, do not set the vertical option as that overrides the auto-detection." However as soon as those parameters are set the carousel stops scrolling.